# How to get users click a map (OSM) and collect location data plus parameters?

Tags: openstreetmap, data-collection

I wonder if there is a simple service out there on the web that allows to collect location data from users easily. A click on a OSM map should give the location, then a form to collect a comment, value, category etc.
Think http://www.fixmystreet.org on a much simpler level, Google Forms with added map, kind of.

Idea: Collect incidents where cyclists experience dangerous situations, generate heat map where most threats are.

Comment: Doing an internet search for "openlayers add markers by click" (or replace openlayers by leafletJS) already results in some hints that may be helpful to you ... tell us in detail where you get stuck by trying both frameworks.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Just hoped for a ready-made solution to handle the map-click at LatLong then collect the data in a form. Like google-froms but with the associated coordinate.